# GitHub Actions SSH no key found

Tags: git, github, deployment, github-actions, cicd

When I try to connect action and upload the application to the server, I get an errortar all files
A private key has been created on the server and all its contents, along with comments at the beginning and at the end, are inserted into the KEY variable

> into /tmp/UMKcNkVePP.tar.gz
> 2023/09/07 11:56:27 ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found
> 2023/09/07 11:56:38 ssh.ParsePrivateKey: ssh: no key found
> remote server os type is unix
> 2023/09/07 11:56:39 error copy file to dest: ***, error message: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain
> scp file to server.
> drone-scp error:  error copy file to dest: ***, error message: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain

the yml code itself

```
name: deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          source: "."
          target: /
          strip_components: 1
```

I tried to set environment variables through different places, environments, actions, but nothing helps
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you try a step to echo the secret or some other dummy value? also try setting a "env:" and then use the env.KEY in the with params.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the first part of your idea

Comment: trial 1 to see if secrets have proper data 
    - name: ECHO SECRET
      run: |
        - echo ${{ secrets.KEY }}

Comment: I checked, he output the key value through env: it didn't help either

Comment: Is that secret a private key or a public key?

Comment: its private key

Comment: You must include the separators (-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----).

Comment: I did just that

Comment: did it worked? Are you able to resolve it?